# Multiple facet filters with Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

How can I apply multiple filters to facet (with tire gem)? I have a code:

```
facet "packages" do
  terms :package
  facet_filter :terms, producer: [*params[:producer]] if params[:producer].present?
  facet_filter :terms, category_id: [*params[:category_id]] if params[:category_id].present?
end
```

But it seems to apply only the last filter. But I need both of them.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
my_filter = []
my_filter << {:terms => {:producer => [*params[:producer]] }} if params[:producer].present?
my_filter << {:terms => { :producer => [*params[:category_id]] }} if params[:category_id].present?

facet "packages" do
  terms :package
  facet_filter :and, my_filter
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work - 'filter malformed, must start with start_object', but I think I get the general direction.

Comment: updated, have only ever tried it with :term queries, so YMMV. Let me know how it goes

Comment: I discovered the correct syntax shortly after reading this, indeed this works and nicely. Thanks.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Someone with enough reputation, please accept.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_filter = []
my_filter << {:term => {:producer => params[:producer] }} if params[:producer].present?
my_filter << {:term => {:category_id => params[:category_id] }} if params[:category_id].present?

facet "packages" do
  terms :package
  facet_filter(:and, my_filter) if my_filter.present?
end
```